Strange Output in VSCode with Python 3.12.3: Unusual Characters and File Paths
enter image description here
I'm encountering a peculiar issue while running Python code in Visual Studio Code (VSCode) with Python 3.12.3. When I execute a simple print("Hello") statement, the output in the VSCode terminal includes strange characters and file paths that seem to be mangled. Here's an example of the output I'm seeing:

PS C:\Users\DELL>  c:; cd 'c:\Users\DELL'; & 'c:\Users\DELL\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\python.exe' 'c:\Users\DELL.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.6.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\adapter/../..\debugpy\launcher' '60081' '--' 'C:\Users\DELL\Untitled-1.py'
cadapter/../..\x5cdebugpy\x5clauncher' '60081' '--' 'C:\x5cUsers\x5cDELL\x5cUntitled-1.py' ;c75f735e-9e3e-45a8-b2bb-65c86727b88bLOL

I've tried checking for escape characters in my code, ensuring correct file path handling, and updating both VSCode and Python to their latest versions. However, the issue persists.
Has anyone else encountered a similar problem with VSCode and Python 3.12.3? Any insights or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
The expected output should simply be:

LOL


This is just the Run/Debug procedure showing you how your script is being executed. The \x5c sequences are just backslashes. You wouldn't see that on a proper operating system

It seems you don’t give a file name to your python file. CTRL+Shift+P than type >Python:Run Python File in Terminal should show you the right output, if your environment variable are set correctly to your python.exe environment.
For beginners it’s a good idea, use an easy editor like Thonny.
